# Вывод из txt файла по имени логина записанному значению абонента php

Tags: php

есть `test1.txt` файл в нем хранятся данные в построчно

```
test 12.12.12 9.00
test 13.12.12 9.15
test 14.12.12 9.00
test1 14.12.12 9.00
test1 15.12.12 9.00
```

первое значение является записанным значением и переданным методом `$_POST['name']` что изначально являлось логином при входе
подскажите как по средствам php когда на сайте пользователь test то ему показывались лишь строчки с наименованием test а когда залогинится test 1 то только строчки с стартовой подписью test1 - также дабы не выглядеть полным неудачником привожу свой неудачный скрипт в этом вопросе который мне целиком выдает на страницу все записи в не зависимости кто залогинился

```
$hanble = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
while (!feof($hanble)){
$bufer = fgets($hanble);
echo "$bufer" <br/>;
}


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['myActionName'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo date(" Y:m:d H:i:s ");
    $test1 = date(" Y:m:d H:i:s ");
    $fp = fopen("test1.txt", 'a');
    $test = fwrite($fp, $_POST['name'] . $test1 . "\r\n");
    if ($test) {
        echo " Данные записаны";
    } else {
        echo " Ошибка записи";
    }
    fclose($fp); //закрыли файл

    $pos = $_POST['name'];
    $handle = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $bufer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($bufer, $_POST['name'] . ' '))
            echo $bufer . "\r\n";введите сюда код
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

---

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['myActionName'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo date(" Y:m:d H:i:s ");
    $test1 = date(" Y:m:d H:i:s ");
    $fp = fopen("test1.txt", 'a');
    $test = fwrite($fp, $_POST['name'] . $test1 . "\r\n");
    if ($test) {
        echo " Данные записаны";
    } else {
        echo " Ошибка записи";
    }
    fclose($fp); //закрыли файл

    $pos = $_POST['name'];
    $hanble = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($hanble)) {введите сюда код
        $bufer = fgets($hanble);`введите сюда код`
        echo "$bufer <br/>";
    }
    fclose($hanble);
}
```

а это изначально работающий но не правильно - он показывает все что есть в файле

---

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<?php
if (isset($_POST['myActionName'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo date(" Y:m:d H:i:s ");
    $test1 = date(" Y:m:d H:i:s ");
    $fp = fopen("test1.txt", 'a');
    $test = fwrite($fp, $_POST['name'] . $test1 . "\r\n");
    if ($test) {
        echo " Данные записаны";
    } else {
        echo " Ошибка записи";
    }
    fclose($fp); //закрыли файл

    $pos = $_POST['name'];
    $handle = fopen("test1.txt", "r");
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $bufer = fgets($handle);
        if(strpos($bufer, $_POST['name'] . ' '))
            echo $bufer . "\r\n";введите сюда код
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

вот вся страничка(((((

Comment: `if(strpos($buffer, $_POST['name'].' ')!==false) echo $buffer;`

Comment: после добавления все пропало - буквально все что выдавалось исчезло(

Comment: У вас `$bufer`, а я написал `$buffer`. Поменяйте или там или там, но учтите, что я написал правильно. Да, еще - не `hanble`, а `handle`

Comment: Вы неправильно код скопировали из моего коммента. Там еще `!==false` есть

Comment: Да вы совершенно правы)))) Спасибо вам огроменное)))) я над этой станицей уже третьи сутки играсля - вы мене очень сильно помогли - если могу как то поставить лайк или чемто вас отблагодарить вы только скажите